# Character frequency switch statement increasing wrong index

Tags: c#

```cs
public int MaxNumberOfBalloons(string text)
{
    // arr = {b, a, l, o, n}
    int[] arr = new int[5];

    foreach (char ch in text)
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 'b':
                Console.WriteLine(ch);
                arr[0]++;
                break;
            case 'a':
                arr[1]++;
                break;
            case 'l':
                arr[2]++;
                break;
            case 'o':
                arr[3]++;
                break;
            case 'n':
                arr[4]++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    int counter = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Before");

    displayArr(arr);

    while (checkArr(arr))
    {
        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            if (i == 2 || i == 3)
            {
                arr[i] -= 2;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[i]--;
            }
        }

        counter++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("After");

    displayArr(arr);

    return counter;
}

public bool checkArr(int[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 2)
        {
            if (arr[i] > 1)
                continue;
            else
                return false;
        }
        if (i == 3)
        {
            if (arr[i] > 1)
                continue;
            else
                return false;
        }
        if (arr[i] == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Test results for input string: text = "bb"

Console output before the while loop:

```
b
b
Before
0
2
2
2
2
```

After the while loop:

```
After
0
2
2
2
2
```

`counter` returned 1.

Question: Why is the switch statement not working as expected?

Observation: Is increasing all the other index except for the one that is supposed to. I wrote a Console.WriteLine in the case that is suppose to land twice and it did, but it increased all the other index except for that one.

The display method is very straight forward: A simple iterator that outputs the content of each index in the array passed to it.

In the main, I just simply call the `MaxNumberOfBalloons` method and pass it a string.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. Step through your code line-by-line and see where your logic is failing (or where the input data is not as expected). It's not clear what you're _expecting_ the output to be to know where it could be going wrong.

Comment: You also don't show the code for `displayArr` to see if _that_ could be the problem.

Comment: And there is also not specified what is the `text` on input. How do you invoke the method?

Comment: Running your code with a simple implementation of `displayArr` shows the correct output (for 'Before', at least)

Comment: @DStanley I mention both what I expect and my observations in the comments. DisplayArr is also explained in the comments. text is also explained in the comments.

Comment: @stuartd my expectation of an output would be that for the string text = "bb" I would get in arr[0] a value of 2, since the character b is repeated twice. Instead, am getting a value of 2 in all the other index except for that specific index

Comment: Try to use https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and see if you can reproduce the error.

Comment: @eglease https://dotnetfiddle.net/gLllOx

Comment: @diegoc the reason I asked for the _code_ instead of an _explanation_ is exactly because of bugs like you had. Even the most seemingly simple functions can have bugs that throw off your investigation significantly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with `displayArr`.

If I change it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
}
```

You are not printing the array but the index of the array based on the value of the array.

It works correctly.

So instead of printing `arr[0]`, which is `2`; you are printing `arr[arr[0]]` which is the same as `arr[2]`, which is `0`.

```
foreach (int i in arr)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

This is a very interesting bug and took me a while to see.

Comment: I had to print `i` to see what was going on.  Not that easy to solve.

Comment: I was so wrong and I apologize to everyone on this thread. This was def my fault. Thank you all.

Comment: This was a hard bug.  Nothing to apologize for.  You did a great job with dotnetfiddle.  If this solved your problem please mark the answer as the solution.